# Using methods of Enumerable in custom Class

Tags: ruby

I was experimenting with Enumerable and Comparable. I read the documentation and wanted to try it out.

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color
end

class Fruit
  include Enumerable
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :apples

  def initialize
    @apples = []
  end

  def <=> o
    @apple.color <=> o.color
  end

  def each
    @apples.each {|apple| yield apple }
  end

  def to_s
    "apple: #{@apple.color}"
  end
end

fruit = Fruit.new
a1 = Apple.new
a1.color = :red
a2 = Apple.new 
a2.color = :green
a3 = Apple.new
a3.color = :yellow
fruit.apples.push a1
fruit.apples.push a2
fruit.apples.push a3
```

Two things are not working as expected. So I override to_s, I expect each index of array to contain a string like "apple: red". Instead I get this:

```
fruit.sort
 => [#<Apple:0x007fbf53971048 @apples=[], @color=:green>, #<Apple:0x007fbf53999890 @apples=[], @color=:red>, #<Apple:0x007fbf5409b530 @apples=[], @color=:yellow>]
```

Second issue is when I include Enumerable, the instance methods of Enumerable should have been added to the ancestor chain right before the inherited classes. This should have included methods of Enumerable like with_each, reduce, etc to the ancestor chain. However, when I do this:

```
fruit.each.with_index(1).reduce({}) do |acc,(apple,i)|
  acc << { i => apple.color}
end
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

as you can see, I get a LocalJumpError. I expected a result like this:

```
{ 1 => :red, 2 => :green, 3 => :yellow}
```

What am I doing wrong? I defined `each` like I was supposed to yet it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your naming convention is a bit odd. Most people would consider an apple to be a fruit. Having a fruit that can contain apples is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I override to_s, I expect each index of array to contain a string like "apple: red". Instead I get this: ...

Two things are wrong here.

1) you have to implement `Apple#to_s`, not `Fruit#to_s`:

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color

  def to_s
    "apple: #{color}"
  end
end
```

2) you have to implement [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) or define it as an [alias](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias):

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color

  def to_s
    "apple: #{color}"
  end
  alias inspect to_s
end
```

This will give you:

```
fruit = Fruit.new
a1 = Apple.new
a1.color = :red
a2 = Apple.new
a2.color = :green
a3 = Apple.new
a3.color = :yellow
fruit.apples.push a1
fruit.apples.push a2
fruit.apples.push a3

fruit
#=> #<Fruit:0x00007faa3686b7c0 @apples=[apple: red, apple: green, apple: yellow]>
```

---

> Second issue is when I include Enumerable, the instance methods of Enumerable should have been added to the ancestor chain ...

When you write:

```
fruit.each.with_index(1)
```

you are calling `with_index` on the return value of `each`. That's where the error occurs:

```
fruit.each
#=> LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

You have to return an instance of `Enumerator` when no block is given. This can be achieved using a conditional (see [mudasobwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870268/477037)) or by passing the block along:

```
def each(&block)
  @apples.each(&block)
end
```

---

There's another issue with your code: not `Fruit` but `Apple` is the class that should implement `<=>` and include `Comparable`. Because when sorting `@apples`, the items are being compared to each other:

```
class Apple
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :color

  def <=> o
    color <=> o.color
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note that there's a catch when including `Enumerable`. Although you are able to use all those methods, you can easily lose your wrapping class and end up with a plain array:

```
fruit
#=> #<Fruit:0x00007faa3686b7c0 @apples=[apple: red, apple: green, apple: yellow]>

fruit.sort
#=> [apple: green, apple: red, apple: yellow]
```

Answer (score 3):

Return an [`Enumerator::Lazy#enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-enum_for) when no block is given:

```
def each
  @apples.each
end
```

`Array` does that on it’s own, hence the above is already possible. The code inside is effectively similar to:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?

  @apples.each { |apple| yield apple }
end
```

---

What you see in `pry`/`irb` is the result of `inspect`, not `to_s`.